# Share a specific view inside an app

Tags: spotify

How can I share a specific view inside an app by the standard share popover like this?

```
models.application.showSharePopup(document.getElementById("share_playlist"), "spotify:app:whatsnew:home");
```

This give the error

```
Uncaught Error: The provided URI cannot be shared.
```

Comment: I have also tried this, it doesn't work but it should. Spotify, please make the share dialog capable of sharing app uri:s!

Answer (score 0):

In short: You can't. The share popover currently only supports sharing a few items, such as tracks, artists, albums and playlists.